# Difference between Protractor and Grunt?

Tags: javascript, selenium, gruntjs, protractor

On the Protractor site (http://www.protractortest.org/#/infrastructure), it says Protractor uses Selenium for browser automation. Then on the Grunt site (http://gruntjs.com/) it says Grunt is also for automation. If they are both for automation, I'm not sure what are the differences between the two and how they fit together. In some ways, my question is this: Why would I need Grunt if I'm using Protractor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Automation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation) itself is quite a broad term.

These are completely different tools:

- `protractor` is a wrapper around WebDriverJS and used for end-to-end testing
- `grunt` is a javascript task runner

You can actually [run `protractor` tests via `grunt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner).

Comment: Can you please give a use-case to put things into perspective for me? For example, if you were running a set of tests, when does Protractor come into play, and when does Grunt come into play?

Comment: @user1993824 may I refer you to several related blogposts: https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/testing-angularjs-part-5-protractor-grunt/, http://programmerbuddy.blogspot.com/2014/03/full-automation-of-protractor-e2e-tests.html. Hope after reading what is there you have a clearer picture. Thanks.